# Where to get the Glade catalog for vte-2.91 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, glade

From where can I get the the Glade catalog for `vte-2.91` in Ubuntu 20.04?

The catalog file is `/usr/share/glade/catalogs/vte-2.91.xml`.

In prior versions, such as Ubuntu 18.04, the catalog file was available from package `libvte-2.91-dev`.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libvte-2.91-dev/filelist

However, in Ubuntu 20.04, the file is missing from this package:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libvte-2.91-dev/filelist

Is it available in a different package or from another source?

Answer (score 0):

Search using packages.ubuntu.com and `apt-file` on local machine gives no results for `vte-2.91.xml`.

So actual way to fix is to get this package directly from 18.04 LTS repository. **It may break something, so be careful.**
Download and install with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte2.91/libvte-2.91-dev_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte2.91/libvte-2.91-0_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte2.91/libvte-2.91-common_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vte2.91/gir1.2-vte-2.91_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libvte-2.91-dev_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb ./libvte-2.91-0_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb ./libvte-2.91-common_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_all.deb ./gir1.2-vte-2.91_0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2_amd64.deb
```

Then check:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S vte-2.91.xml
> libvte-2.91-dev:amd64: /usr/share/glade/catalogs/vte-2.91.xml
> ```

And finally versions with:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-vte
Package: gir1.2-vte-2.91
Pin: version 0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libvte-2.91-0
Pin: version 0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libvte-2.91-common
Pin: version 0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libvte-2.91-dev
Pin: version 0.52.2-1ubuntu1~18.04.2
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

---

Note: to revert the changes remove pin file with `sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-vte` and upgrade the packages by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.